# Making graph with specific nodes

Tags: python, graph-theory

I'm trying to print a graph, but in the matrix representation of the graph there's a node that has no edges and so I would like to not have it in the printed graph.
I can't change the matrix so I can't remove the rows and columns where the node is at, so that's unfortunately out of the question.
I was thinking making a subgraph of the original graph, but I don't know how not to add that specific node without any edges because in theory I don't know what the matrix is to begin with.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some example code

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
[0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0]])

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)
layout = nx.spring_layout(G)

sizes = [500 for node in G.nodes()]

color_map = ['b' for node in G.nodes()]

nx.draw(G, layout, with_labels=True, node_size=sizes, node_color=color_map)

labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=layout, edge_labels=labels)

plt.show()
```

Comment: A graph vertex with zero edges can be easily found as their corresponding row and column  are all zeros. You can first detect the list of vertices with zero edges, then create a new graph (matrix) with the remaining vertices.

Comment: Looking further into networkx, it seems to have the capability of doing that for you. Checkout the [documentation for `isolates()` and `remove_nodes_from()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isolate.isolates.html#networkx.algorithms.isolate.isolates)